# What is a short phrase that means "how long it takes something to sell"?

Tags: phrase-requests

This phrase would be used as the title or short description of a set of data. Some ideas that I've thought of so far:

- **"Time to Sell"**: This is the one I like the most so far, although it can be misconstrued as an assertion; it is "time to sell".
- **"Sell Time"**: A bit ambiguous - when you Google this results are related to the act of *selling one's time*.
- **"Turnaround Time"**: Also ambiguous as turnaround time is not specific to the act of selling something.

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If the item is real estate, this is often called "days on the market".

Comment: Also turnover time.

Comment: *Turnaround: 3 days* should be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_on_market

**Days on market** (DOM, alternatively **active days on market**, **market time**, or **time on market**) is a measurement of the age of a real estate listing. The statistic is defined as the total number of days the listing is on the active market before either an offer is accepted or the agreement between real estate broker and seller ends.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/inventoryturnover.asp

**Inventory Turnover**

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a single item (as in real estate etc) then "days on market" is probably best. But in the general case of inventory, this is often called the **turn rate** or **turnover rate**.

Answer (score 0):

**Days in inventory** may be a possibility. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_in_inventory):

**Days in inventory** (also known as "Inventory Days of Supply", "Days Inventory Outstanding" or the "Inventory Period" ) is an efficiency ratio that measures the average number of days the company holds its inventory before selling it.